# Get the corresponding icon for a type of node in Maya

Tags: qt, icons, maya, mel, maya-api

I want to use the same icons the outliner shows for the nodes in Maya in my Qt tool inside Maya?. Is there any way to find the path of the icons or the icons in Qt of nodes I have depending on the type?

Is there... any way to get those icons using code at all?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method to set the icon automatically as per the node type. But looking into the pattern of **icon image name** you can query the node type and then set the icon image accordingly.

Reference - **nodeIconButton** - Python examples (from maya documentation)

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

window = cmds.window( )
cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
cmds.nodeIconButton( style='iconOnly', command='cmds.sphere()', image1='sphere.png' )
cmds.nodeIconButton( style='iconAndTextHorizontal', command='cmds.spotLight()', image1='spotlight.png', label='Spot Light' )
cmds.showWindow( window )
```

Here node type would be **sphere** and icon would be **sphere.png**.
Same would be for **spotLight** where corresponding icon would be **spotlight.png**.

Put the corresponding node type name as prefix for icon png which should work for most of the node types.

Comment: You can also create an associative array with for each type of node, the icon name associated that you searched yourself.

Comment: That's awesome guys! . I'll accept the answer when I test this in the following month (no idea when). Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried to use this. It looks fantastic. But it keeps creating empty shelves each time I call that (obviously). I tried storing that nodeIconButton in a variable and getting the icon by using .icon() 
But it returns a unicode string.

How could I create the item without adding it , just to create it, get the icon, and then delete it?

Comment: You may keep the check/condition in your cmd/code itself. If the object exists, you may ignore creation process, else it should create. By this it wont create for each instance the function is called. Does that answer your question?